# Text color and element colors are changed in oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

**Text color of DatePickerDialog gets white in oreo(Google pixel) devices as per below image which is looks perfect in pre-oreo devices.**

[image]

**Also drawer menu fonts become white as per below image which is again looks perfect in pre-oreo devices.**

[image]

**Disable Switch color become white as per below image**

[image]

**In my gradle file :**

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
targetSdkVersion 26

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Style.xml :

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
>     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/newcolorPrimaryDark</item>
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
>     <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
>     <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
>     <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
>     <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
>     <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
>
>     <!-- Active thumb color & Active track color(30% transparency) -->
>     <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
>     <!-- Inactive thumb color -->
>     <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/white</item>
>     <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
>     <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/white</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="AppDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item> //Your custom background color
> </style>
>
> <!--this will reduce space between actionBar Icons-->
> <style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
>     <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dip</item>
>     <item name="android:paddingRight">5dip</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="StarRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
>     <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/bg_rating_bar</item>
>     <item name="android:numStars">5</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
>     <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_bar_selector</item>
>     <!--<item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/white</item>
>     <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>-->
> </style>
>
> <style name="Widget.CardContent" parent="android:Widget">
>     <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
>     <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
>     <item name="android:paddingTop">24dp</item>
>     <item name="android:paddingBottom">24dp</item>
>     <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MenuLabelsStyle">
>     <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
>     <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
>     <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
>     <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
>     <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MenuButtonsStyle">
>     <item name="fab_size">normal</item>
>     <item name="fab_showAnimation">@anim/jump_from_down</item>
>     <item name="fab_hideAnimation">@anim/jump_to_down</item>
>     <item name="fab_shadowColor">#444</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorNormal">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorPressed">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorRipple">?attr/rippleColor</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MenuButtonsSmall">
>     <item name="fab_size">mini</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorNormal">#1565C0</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorPressed">#2272CD</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorRipple">#62B2FF</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MenuButtonsSmall.Green">
>     <item name="fab_colorNormal">#43A047</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorPressed">#2E7D32</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorRipple">#1B5E20</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MenuButtonsSmall.AppColor">
>     <item name="fab_colorNormal">@color/colorPrimaryTrans</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorPressed">@color/colorPrimaryDarkTrans</item>
>     <item name="fab_colorRipple">@color/colorAccentTrans</item>
>     <item name="fab_size">normal</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="FavTextInput1" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
>     <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
>     <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray_9ea</item>
>     <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
>     <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
>     <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gray_9ea</item>
>     <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
> </style>
> <style name="FavTextInput2" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
>     <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
>     <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray_9ea</item>
>     <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
>     <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
>     <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gray_9ea</item>
>     <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="TextLabel" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
>     <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white_lite</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="TextError" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
>     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_lite</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="Color1SwitchStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
>     <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
>     <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/light_gray</item>
>     <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/dark_gray</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
>     <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/black</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
>     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
>
> </style> </resources>
> ```

Let me know if any more information want.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your `styles.xml`

Comment: @azizbekian Please check edited question with styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

Check your res/Values/Styles.xml

https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

What you should take closer took at is:

1. Style parent
2. Play around with: "textColorSecondary","textColor"